# Dynamic section in JSF

Tags: jsf, dynamic

I have a jsf form in which I want to display dynamic section. I have a command link on the html table which opens up new form and displays table rows. My requirement is,  I want to create a dynamic section on this popup form which will display the details of each row in it by hitting the db. The JSF code which displays the pop-up is as follows:

```html
 <a4j:commandLink reRender="for_documentDialogForm"
                  action="#{messageAction.showTableRows(msg)}"
                  onclick="showDialog();" ajaxSingle="true">`
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.patientFName}" />
 </a4j:commandLink>
```

The showDialog() opens the popup(for_documentDialogForm) and displays the table rows. This new popup should contain the dynamic section which will display the details of each row.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather you are using RichFaces (a4j), why not use `<rich:popupPanel>` instead?

Here's the [doc](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky)..

bu it would be something along this line...

```
<a4j:commandLink reRender="for_documentDialogForm"
                  action="#{messageAction.showTableRows(msg)}"
                  oncomplete="#{rich:component('dPopupPanel')}.show()">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg.patientFName}" />
 </a4j:commandLink>

.....

<rich:popupPanel id="dPopupPanel" modal="true" autosized="true">
   <p> The content...</p>
</rich:popupPanel>
```